# How can I transform this object in React-Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a object like so

```js
{ -L1Rm6VbfLLyFJ3Qi6K: {city: "Tokyo", date: "26-08-2004" } }
```

and I want to transform this object like this:

```js
{ id:"-L1Rm6VbfLLyFJ3Qi6K", city: "Tokyo", date: "26-08-2004" }
```

How can I do that? Thank you...

Comment: Use lodash , map !

Comment: I don't want to push this object to an array, I know this way...

Comment: Can your object have multiple keys ?

Comment: Just as above not much

Answer (score 1):

You can take [**Object.entries**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [**map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) them in desired format.

```js
let obj = { '-L1Rm6VbfLLyFJ3Qi6K': {city: "Tokyo", date: "26-08-2004" } }

let op = Object.entries(obj).map(([key,value]) => ({
  id: key,
  ...value,
}))

console.log(op)
```

Comment: I dont want to push this object to an array, all I want is an Object...

Comment: @SerdarGun You can access the object inside array, can't you ? does your input has only one such structure or there can be plenty ?

Comment: I don't know, there is a problem in my App and I am trying all different way in my code. I just wanted to learn this way, it may solve my problem :(

Answer (score 1):

if there is only one object/index you can access in this way.

```js
let obj = { '-L1Rm6VbfLLyFJ3Qi6K': {city: "Tokyo", date: "26-08-2004" } }

let op = Object.entries(obj).map(([key,value]) => ({
  id: key,
  ...value,
}))

console.log(op[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

If the object going to be one key value then use this, otherwise, like @Code Maniac suggested, you should use a map or forEach

```js
const obj = { '-L1Rm6VbfLLyFJ3Qi6K': {city: "Tokyo", date: "26-08-2004" } }

const newobj = {
   id: Object.keys(obj)[0],
   ...obj[Object.keys(obj)]
}

console.log(newobj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you looking like this way?

```js
const obj1 = { "-L1Rm6VbfLLyFJ3Qi6K": {city: "Tokyo", date: "26-08-2004" } }

const obj2 = {}

for (const id in obj1) {
  Object.assign(obj2, { id, ...obj1[id] })
}

console.log(obj2);
```

or reusing old object with this way?

```js
const obj1 = { "-L1Rm6VbfLLyFJ3Qi6K": {city: "Tokyo", date: "26-08-2004" } }

for (const id in obj1) {
   Object.assign(obj1, { id, ...obj1[id] })
   delete obj1[id];
}

console.log(obj1);
```